# Is there a way to scroll the table when moving a row?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a `tabulator` table with many items, and moving a row outside the displayed range of rows involves a number of steps (moving, dropping, scrolling, then moving again, etc.)

Has anyone come up with a method to scroll the table when the user drags a row above or below the displayed range? Here is a gif and a JSFiddle which demonstrates the problem.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/sunny001/puqwemnf/5/

---

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    data.push({id: i, name: 'name' + i})
}

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
    height: 400,
    data: data,
  movableRows: true,
  columns: [
    {
     rowHandle: true,
     formatter: "handle",
     headerSort: false,
     frozen: true,
     width: 30,
     minWidth: 30
    },
    {field: 'id', title: 'id'},
    {field: 'name', title: 'name'}
  ],
  selectable: true
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the "problem". When I drag a table row down, the table scrolls and I drop the row in place. When I then grab a row and drag up, the tables scrolls in the opposite direction and allows me to drop the row there. What am I missing?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I don't see that happening in Firefox or Chrome, so this might be a browser-specific problem that `tabulator` might have [an issue open for](http://tabulator.info/community#contribute-issues). Did you check, @spring?

Comment: I see -- Chrome does not work, while Safari does. Interesting.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - yes, it appears to be posted as a bug as of 12/18/20 - https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3137

Comment: In that case I guess it probably makes sense to put that in your post, and ask people if they know a workaround, so that it's clear that you know you're asking about how to deal with a known bug. (but then you also kind of take on the responsibility to comment on the bug with whatever workaround people end up recommending)